# Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are not both zero, and $c\neq0$. Prove that $c.$gcd($a,b$)$\leq$gcd($ca,cb$).

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

I am going through the Book of Poof, by Richard Hammack, and in the chapter on direct proof, I came across this exercise:

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are not both zero, and $c\neq0$. Prove that $c.$gcd($a,b$)$\leq$gcd($ca,cb$).

My proof is the following:

Suppose $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $a$ and $b$ are not both zero, and $c\neq0$.

Notice that gcd($a,b$) is always positive, because they are not both $0$. This is true, because if $d\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$, then $-d$ is also, thus, $|d|$ is a divisor of $a$ and $b$. Since gcd($a,b$) is the greatest common divisor, it is always a positive one.

Let $k=$gcd($a,b$). Thus, $k\mid a$ and $k\mid b$. By definition of divisibility, there are integers $x,y$ such that $a=kx$ and $b=ky$.Notice $x$ and $y$ have no common factors, because if $w$ was a common factor of $x$ and $y$, we could write $x=wz_1$ and $y=wz_2$, but that would mean $a=kwz_1$ and $b=kwz_2$, thus, $|kw|$ would be a divisor of both $a$ and $b$ and $|kw|>k=$gcd($a,b$), which is absurd. Hence, gcd($x,y$)$=1$.

Also, $ca=ckx$ and $cb=cky$. Since gcd($x,y$)$=1$, it follows that $|ck|$ is the gcd($ca,cb$).

Case 1: $\mathbf{c>0}$. This means gcd($ca,cb$)$=|ck|=ck=c.$gcd($a,b$).

Case 2: $\mathbf{c<0}$. This means gcd($ca,cb$)$=|ck|>ck=c.$gcd($a,b$).

In either case, $c.$gcd($a,b$)$\leq$gcd($ca,cb$). $\blacksquare$

Is this correct? Any tips on improving my proof writting? Should I have proved the claim "if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a divisor of both $a$ and $b$, then $-x$ is also" or is it ok to assume the reader would find this obvious as I did?

Comment: "Should I have proved the claim "if x∈Z is a divisor of both a and b, then −x is also" or is it ok to assume the reader would find this obvious"  In my opinion I'd have said *less* ... BTW it is not that $\gcd(a,b)$ is positive *because* they are both non zero.  It is *finite* because they are both non-zero.

Comment: I feel it a strange question as it hints at a far more conceptually useful and meaningful statement that $\gcd(ca,cb) = |c|\gcd(a,b)$.  That's a *far* more useful and powerful result and conceptually much more important.  (... In case 2 I'd add $\gcd(ca,cb)=|ck| > 0 > ck=c\cdot \gcd(a,b)$.  That gets more to point as to why $|ck|>ck$ (because one is positive and the other neg.) And it gets to $c\gcd(a,b)$ is either equal to $\gcd(ca,cb)$ or it is negative which is the only reason we indicate $\le$.